# Stop PhpStorm from opening files when debugging

Tags: php, phpstorm

In PhpStorm 2018.1 is there a way to stop the debugger from automatically opening files in new tabs as it steps through said files?

Comment: If those files are executed, and they have lines marked to debug, then the IDE will open them and stop on that lines. It is different for the first file that is executed, which may be opened because it is out of the project's directory scope.

Comment: Make max 1 editor tab policy. Otherwise -- nope -- it works the same as if you just open some random project file -- it will be opened in new tab.